# (Java Interface) What does (Interface_name)class_name.newInstance() Mean in java?

Tags: java

code :

```
interface MyInterface {
    void connect();
}
class SQLconnection implements MyInterface {
    public void connect() {
        System.out.println("Connection successful to SQL database");
    }
}
class OracleConnection implements MyInterface {
    public void connect() {
        System.out.println("Connection successful to Oracle database");
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String class_name = args[0];
        Class c = Class.forName(class_name);
        MyInterface obj = (MyInterface)c.newInstance();
        obj.connect();
    }
}
```

I am learning about interface from book, and the following code was written. What does the below line mean?

```
MyInterface obj = (MyInterface)c.newInstance();
```

Comment: It is called `casting`

Comment: but we can create an object of Interface right? @Scary Wombat

Comment: If your code did `SQLconnection conn = new SQLconnection ();` then you would not need to do any casting.  But the above code is using `reflection` in instantiate an `Object` which then needs to be `casted` to your class/interface.

Comment: @Scary Womba Please have a look https://codeshare.io/2pNYjY

Comment: `obj.connect();` will not work - Object does not have a method called `connect` this is why it needs to be casted.

Comment: Sorry for annoying you but, what about MyInterface obj = c.newInstance();

Comment: Did you try it?  Maybe quicker than waiting for a reply from me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`c.newInstance()` will return you an instance if `Object` class (which is the parent of all classes).

But the `connect()` method is defined in your `MyInterface` interface and not in the `Object` class.

So you type caste from `Object` to `MyInterface` and then call the `connect()` method on it.

Please note, this type casting will only be possible if `class_name` = <name of a class which implements `MyInterface` >

Answer (score 0):

The Factory pattern in Java often uses the **newInstance()** method to create objects, lots of exapmles can be found on why the factory pattern is used. For example as followed:

```
class c = Class.forName("Example");
factory = (ExampleInterface)c.newInstance();
```

**Notice:** 
I think you may confuse about that why the code does not use "new" keyword to create a new object.

This is my answer: 
When initializing a class and generating an instance, the main difference between the **newInstance()** method and the keyword **"new"** except that one is a method and another one is a keyword?

The difference between them is that the way of creating objects is different. The former uses the **class loading mechanism**, and the latter one just **creates a new class**. So why are there two ways to create objects? This mainly considers software design ideas such as software scalability, scalability, and reusability.

Comment: What was the need/use to cast the object into Interface? I mean (ExampleInterface)object